# customer group sorting return error in magento admin panel

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

In our magento admin panel, we used the `group` column to sort the customers.

But it displays query with errors.

That means when click on the `group` column it goes to magento admin `dashboard`.

So we clicked again in Manage Customers Link but it now displays error with query.

The following is the query with errors:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `at_prefix`.`value` AS `prefix`, `at_firstname`.`value` AS `firstname`, `at_middlename`.`value` AS `middlename`, `at_lastname`.`value` AS `lastname`, `at_suffix`.`value` AS `suffix`, CONCAT(IF(at_prefix.value IS NOT NULL AND at_prefix.value != '', CONCAT(LTRIM(RTRIM(at_prefix.value)), ' '), ''), LTRIM(RTRIM(at_firstname.value)), ' ', IF(at_middlename.value IS NOT NULL AND at_middlename.value != '', CONCAT(LTRIM(RTRIM(at_middlename.value)), ' '), ''), LTRIM(RTRIM(at_lastname.value)), IF(at_suffix.value IS NOT NULL AND at_suffix.value != '', CONCAT(' ', LTRIM(RTRIM(at_suffix.value))), '')) AS `name`, `at_default_billing`.`value` AS `default_billing`, `at_billing_postcode`.`value` AS `billing_postcode`, `at_billing_city`.`value` AS `billing_city`, `at_billing_telephone`.`value` AS `billing_telephone`, `at_billing_region`.`value` AS `billing_region`, `at_billing_country_id`.`value` AS `billing_country_id`, `at_group_id`.`value` AS `group_id` FROM `customer_entity` AS `e`
 LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_prefix` ON (`at_prefix`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_prefix`.`attribute_id` = '4')
 LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_firstname` ON (`at_firstname`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_firstname`.`attribute_id` = '5')
 LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_middlename` ON (`at_middlename`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_middlename`.`attribute_id` = '6')
 LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_lastname` ON (`at_lastname`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_lastname`.`attribute_id` = '7')
 LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_suffix` ON (`at_suffix`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_suffix`.`attribute_id` = '8')
 LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_int` AS `at_default_billing` ON (`at_default_billing`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_default_billing`.`attribute_id` = '13')
 LEFT JOIN `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_billing_postcode` ON (`at_billing_postcode`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`) AND (`at_billing_postcode`.`attribute_id` = '30')
 LEFT JOIN `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_billing_city` ON (`at_billing_city`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`) AND (`at_billing_city`.`attribute_id` = '26')
 LEFT JOIN `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_billing_telephone` ON (`at_billing_telephone`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`) AND (`at_billing_telephone`.`attribute_id` = '31')
 LEFT JOIN `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_billing_region` ON (`at_billing_region`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`) AND (`at_billing_region`.`attribute_id` = '28')
 LEFT JOIN `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_billing_country_id` ON (`at_billing_country_id`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`) AND (`at_billing_country_id`.`attribute_id` = '27')
 LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `at_group_id` ON (`at_group_id`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_group_id`.`attribute_id` = '10') WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '1') ORDER BY `group_id` ASC LIMIT 20
```

When we excuting this query phpmyadmin->SQL it return error as:

```
#1052 - Column 'group_id' in order clause is ambiguous
```

So how can i solve this?

if there is any problem with my admin panel?

**UPDATE**

This is the function we added in

`D:\wamp\www\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Customer\Grid.php` :

```
protected function _groupFilter($collection, $column){
        $this->getCollection()->getSelect()->where(new Zend_Db_Expr("{$this->getColumn()->getFilterIndex()} like '{$column->getFilter()->getValue()}'"));
        return $this;
    }

 protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->addNameToSelect()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
            ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left');

        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

Amd this the column in `_prepareColumns()` ;

```
 $this->addColumn('group', array(
            'header'    =>  Mage::helper('customer')->__('Group'),
            'width'     =>  '100',
            'index'     =>  'group_id',
            'type'      =>  'options',
            'filter_index' => 'e.group_id',
            'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_groupFilter'),
            'options'   =>  $groups,
        ));
```

Then i got this error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function getFilterIndex() on a non-object in `D:\wamp\www\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Customer\Grid.php on line 65`

This is the error in log file:

```
2013-08-30T06:48:26+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Missing argument 1 for Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::getColumn(), called in D:\wamp\www\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Customer\Grid.php on line 65 and defined  in D:\wamp\www\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php on line 431
2013-08-30T06:48:26+00:00 ERR (3): Notice: Undefined variable: columnId  in D:\wamp\www\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php on line 433
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have altered default grid functionality, right SQl query below. It should be `` e`.`group_id `` in stead of `group_id`.

Hope this can help you.

`SELECT e.*, at_prefix.value AS prefix, at_firstname.value AS firstname, at_middlename.value AS middlename, at_lastname.value AS lastname, at_suffix.value AS suffix, CONCAT(IF(at_prefix.value IS NOT NULL AND at_prefix.value != '', CONCAT(LTRIM(RTRIM(at_prefix.value)), ' '), ''), LTRIM(RTRIM(at_firstname.value)), ' ', IF(at_middlename.value IS NOT NULL AND at_middlename.value != '', CONCAT(LTRIM(RTRIM(at_middlename.value)), ' '), ''), LTRIM(RTRIM(at_lastname.value)), IF(at_suffix.value IS NOT NULL AND at_suffix.value != '', CONCAT(' ', LTRIM(RTRIM(at_suffix.value))), '')) AS name, at_default_billing.value AS default_billing, at_billing_postcode.value AS billing_postcode, at_billing_city.value AS billing_city, at_billing_telephone.value AS billing_telephone, at_billing_region.value AS billing_region, at_billing_country_id.value AS billing_country_id, at_group_id.value AS group_id FROM customer_entity AS e
 LEFT JOIN customer_entity_varchar AS at_prefix ON (at_prefix.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND (at_prefix.attribute_id = '4')
 LEFT JOIN customer_entity_varchar AS at_firstname ON (at_firstname.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND (at_firstname.attribute_id = '5')
 LEFT JOIN customer_entity_varchar AS at_middlename ON (at_middlename.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND (at_middlename.attribute_id = '6')
 LEFT JOIN customer_entity_varchar AS at_lastname ON (at_lastname.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND (at_lastname.attribute_id = '7')
 LEFT JOIN customer_entity_varchar AS at_suffix ON (at_suffix.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND (at_suffix.attribute_id = '8')
 LEFT JOIN customer_entity_int AS at_default_billing ON (at_default_billing.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND (at_default_billing.attribute_id = '13')
 LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar AS at_billing_postcode ON (at_billing_postcode.entity_id = at_default_billing.value) AND (at_billing_postcode.attribute_id = '30')
 LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar AS at_billing_city ON (at_billing_city.entity_id = at_default_billing.value) AND (at_billing_city.attribute_id = '26')
 LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar AS at_billing_telephone ON (at_billing_telephone.entity_id = at_default_billing.value) AND (at_billing_telephone.attribute_id = '31')
 LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar AS at_billing_region ON (at_billing_region.entity_id = at_default_billing.value) AND (at_billing_region.attribute_id = '28')
 LEFT JOIN customer_address_entity_varchar AS at_billing_country_id ON (at_billing_country_id.entity_id = at_default_billing.value) AND (at_billing_country_id.attribute_id = '27')
 LEFT JOIN customer_entity_varchar AS at_group_id ON (at_group_id.entity_id = e.entity_id) AND (at_group_id.attribute_id = '10') WHERE (e.entity_type_id = '1') ORDER BY e.group_id ASC LIMIT 20`

Comment: i got this error after changing `group_id` to `e.group_id` : Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in D:\wamp\www\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php on line 816

Answer (score 0):

You should add to your column the following:

```
$this->addColumn(
   'filter_index' =>'e.group'
)
```

In order to filter, if it still doesn't work try adding this to your column:

```
$this->addColumn(...
    'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_groupFilter'),
     ...
)
```

And add function to your grid class:

```
private function _groupFilter($collection, $column){
    $this->getCollection->getSelect()->where(new Zend_Db_Expr("{$this->getColumn()->getFilterIndex()} like '{$column->getFilter()->getValue())}'"));
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: i got this error after changing `group_id` to `e.group_id` : Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in D:\wamp\www\mysite\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php on line 816

Comment: the error will get on filtering only...but the group sorting not correctly...because it will not sorting the cstomer (but the main error in the question not getting)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this function `$this->getColumn()`, you need to add functional parameter `columnId` on this function. Because of, the actual function is like that,

```
public function getColumn($columnId)
{
    if (!empty($this->_columns[$columnId])) {
        return $this->_columns[$columnId];
    }
    return false;
}
```

`getFilterIndex()` also same. You can't point out without knowing column. This look like `$column->getFilterIndex()`

For you sql syntax error, remove order clause first. Then,test it again. Let me know error.

Hope this snippet can help to you.

Comment: $column->getFilterIndex() instead of $this->getColumn()->getFilterIndex(). Try this. It might be work.

Comment: i already tried this , when i use this there have no error, but have some issues............

Comment: Do you use this function _groupFilter?

Comment: yes it is called in ` 'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_groupFilter'),`

Comment: Comment out this line and remove order clause in your query. Then, try it again. Let me know any result.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36538/discussion-between-kichu-and-thiha)